# MySQL update one column from another columns in same table by adding additional texts

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQl table that contains values as follows :

```
+--------+-----------+------------+---------------+
| item_d | branch_id | item_count | new_item_code |
+--------+-----------+------------+---------------+
|      1 |        20 |          1 |               |
|      1 |         4 |          2 |               |
|      1 |         6 |          3 |               |
|      1 |         2 |          4 |               |
|      1 |        12 |          5 |               |
|      1 |         8 |          6 |               |
+--------+-----------+------------+---------------+
```

Then I need to update the column, named "new_item_code" using values in the first 03 columns.

### Tried

So, I tried with the following command.

```
update item set new_item_code = concatenate(''CSS/'.branch_id.'/'.item_id.'/'.item_count.')
```

### Expected result

And expected to get the follwing output.

```
+--------+-----------+------------+---------------+
| item_d | branch_id | item_count | new_item_code |
+--------+-----------+------------+---------------+
|      1 |        20 |          1 | CSS/20/1/1    |
|      1 |         4 |          2 | CSS/4/1/2     |
|      1 |         6 |          3 | CSS/6/1/3     |
|      1 |         2 |          4 | CSS/2/1/4     |
|      1 |        12 |          5 | CSS/12/1/5    |
|      1 |         8 |          6 | CSS/8/1/6     |
+--------+-----------+------------+---------------+
```

### Error

But the query outs a systax error.

I think that my query need to change further. Can anyone help ?